# Regex for spliting an array on token

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like the following :

```
String s = 100[leetcode].
```

Can I split it into a String array using the `split()` method?

```
String[] arr = s.split("\\s*]+\\s*");
```

So the resulting array becomes:

```
["100"] ["["] ["leetcode"] ["]"].
```

I am not able to figure out the correct regex required for this. Can anybody help on this?

Comment: Perhaps like `(?<=\S)(?=[\[\]])|(?<=[\[\]])(?=\S)` https://regex101.com/r/PlhVOr/1  See https://ideone.com/5KZeAN

Comment: Famous quote: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.'

Seriously, if the regex required is as ugly as the one proposed then your future maintainers will thank you for writing a simple method that traverses the string and splits it where it sees [ or ]

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use lookarounds

```
(?<=\S)(?=[\[\]])|(?<=[\[\]])(?=\S)
```

- `(?<=\S)` Positive lookbehind, if what is on the left is a non whitespace char
- `(?=[\[\]])` Positive lookahead, if what is on the right is either `[` or `]`
- `|` Or
- `(?<=[\[\]])` Positive lookbehind, f what is on the left is either `[` or `]`
- `(?=\S)` Positive lookahead, if what is on the right is a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PlhVOr/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/5KZeAN)

For example in Java

```
String s = "100[leetcode]";
String[] arr = s.split("(?<=\\S)(?=[\\[\\]])|(?<=[\\[\\]])(?=\\S)");
```